# Is there any free tool to create Tile Package?

Tags: tiles

Currently my desktop widget has to work offline mode and I do not have any basemap in .tpk format. I saw an app from Esri called Tile Package Kreator however I think it is not available in stores anymore. Any help or suggestion?

Comment: "Esri Labs projects are released to [the] public as non-commercial offerings but are not official Esri products." They would not be available in any store anywhere anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need either ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro if you want to create a Tile Package.

If using ArcMap you can use the [UI](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/how-to-create-a-tile-package.htm) or you can use the [Create Map Tile Package tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-map-tile-package.htm).
ArcGIS Pro [UI](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/overview/tile-package.htm) help and [Create Map Tile Package Tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-map-tile-package.htm) help.

Answer (score 0):

Tile Package Kreator is still available for download and works quite well

https://github.com/Esri/TilePackageKreator

The download URLs for Windows, Mac, and Linux are on the page above.